# Class properties not applying to all divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a footer `section` which has 4 `div` each having a common class. The first `div` for some reason is taking more width than it should be taking. The remaining 3 `div` are taking the width of the elements in it, why isn't it the case with the first `div`?. I know I can change the dimensions of that `div` manually, but I want to know the reason why this is happening.

[image]

Also, I set a `align-items: flex start` for all the `div`, but the property only seems to apply to the first div.

My HTML and CSS Code:

```css
#footer{
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  height:60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#footer .container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}


.contact-handle img{
  width: 20%;
}

#footer h4{
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#footer p{
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin:0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#footer i{
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
    <div class="contact-handle container">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <p>Address: XXX ABCDE Road, Street 32, Mumbai</p>
      <p>Phone: (+91) 01234 56789/(+01) 2222 365</p>
      <p>Hours: 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Follow Us</h4>
      <div class="social_media">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="About container">
      <h4>About</h4>
      <br>
      <p>About Us</p>
      <p>Delivery Information</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy</p>
      <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
      <p>Conatct Us</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Account container">
      <h4>My Account</h4>
      <br>
      <p>Sign In</p>
      <p>View Cart</p>
      <p>My Wishlist</p>
      <p>Track Order</p>
      <p>Help</p>
    </div>

    <div class="App_gateway container">
      <h4>Install App</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: The `align-items` property is placed on the _parent_, not the children. You have `align-items: center` on the parent now.

Comment: To your primary question... you haven't applied any grow/shrink policy, so the elements take the space they need. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flexbox-properties.

Comment: @isherwood if you look at the remaining 3 div, they take the width of the elements. But the 1st div, is taking more width than the elements' width

Comment: Yep. The first div has longer text. Like I said, the space they need.

Comment: Um, no, it's taking more space than the text inside it. Please take a look at the image I shared with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your particular case can be solved by using rem or em unit

**What really happened?**
when you use flex, the size of each containers are on auto adjusted based on the largest intrinsic dimension of the element inside.

In the first div, it's your image which has the largest intrinsic dimension.

When you tell the image to have 20% of the parent container's width (that's what % means - relative to parent container) the image adjust accordingly. And if you check the width of the parent container, it retained the exact intrinsic value of the image dimension.

I'm not sure why it behaves the way it does (someone more knowledge can comment), the best approach is to usually avoid using % in general and use rem/em.

Here's one using rem:

```css
footer {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 4em 1em;
  /* add padding instead of 60vh height */
}

#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  /* use space-around */

}

#footer .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

img {
  width: 5rem;
}

#footer h4 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#footer p {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#footer i {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <footer>
      <section id="footer">
        <div class="contact-handle container">
          <a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2Fz6Fn5zq_hh75oNLsyNqyGSHzPopHojN77Eu6GImw_3bb4JteONR_K8lnCY2nRbZQV9RD7ACVYvTHEEoW6oGt2GNkAVXzsGdHl1XI9JWwr9ojo3N7t5mYgqaux8lESdvi4mJTti4Ok=w2400?source=screenshot.guru"> <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2Fz6Fn5zq_hh75oNLsyNqyGSHzPopHojN77Eu6GImw_3bb4JteONR_K8lnCY2nRbZQV9RD7ACVYvTHEEoW6oGt2GNkAVXzsGdHl1XI9JWwr9ojo3N7t5mYgqaux8lESdvi4mJTti4Ok=w600-h315-p-k" /> </a>

          <h4>Contact</h4>
          <p>Address: XXX ABCDE Road, Street 32, Mumbai</p>
          <p>Phone: (+91) 01234 56789/(+01) 2222 365</p>
          <p>Hours: 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
          <br>
          <h4>Follow Us</h4>
          <div class="social_media">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="About container">
          <h4>About</h4>
          <br>
          <p>About Us</p>
          <p>Delivery Information</p>
          <p>Privacy Policy</p>
          <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
          <p>Conatct Us</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Account container">
          <h4>My Account</h4>
          <br>
          <p>Sign In</p>
          <p>View Cart</p>
          <p>My Wishlist</p>
          <p>Track Order</p>
          <p>Help</p>
        </div>

        <div class="App_gateway container">
          <h4>Install App</h4>
        </div>
      </section>
    </footer>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you are asking for from the question. However, it appears you have nothing actually setting the dimensions of the divs. That first div with class of container is simply larger because of the info that is in it.

If you change the `justify-content: center;` in your `#footer` selector

to `justify-content: space-between;`

it should give you what I suspect is the desired effect, where everything is spaced evenly.

Also, I wanted to note you are talking about a header but your HTML you posted has a section id of `footer`. Be sure to check everything in your question before you post to avoid any future confusion.

Comment: You should copy the snippet down and demonstrate your solution.

Comment: Hey, it's a footer, typing error. I tried using justify-content: space-between, didn't work. My question is, why is the first div, taking so much width, because the other divs are taking the width of the elements present in it, so why isn't the first one doing that?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to add the `<footer>` element as the parent and set the `background-color` and `height` to that element. Remove `height: 60vh;` and use `height: 100%;` with `padding` to get that extra space. Then just set `align-items: flex-start;` on `#footer`.

```css
footer {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 4em 1em;
  /* add padding instead of 60vh height */
}

#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

#footer .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.contact-handle img {
  width: 20%;
}

#footer h4 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#footer p {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#footer i {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section id="footer">
    <div class="contact-handle container">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <p>Address: XXX ABCDE Road, Street 32, Mumbai</p>
      <p>Phone: (+91) 01234 56789/(+01) 2222 365</p>
      <p>Hours: 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Follow Us</h4>
      <div class="social_media">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="About container">
      <h4>About</h4>
      <br>
      <p>About Us</p>
      <p>Delivery Information</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy</p>
      <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
      <p>Conatct Us</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Account container">
      <h4>My Account</h4>
      <br>
      <p>Sign In</p>
      <p>View Cart</p>
      <p>My Wishlist</p>
      <p>Track Order</p>
      <p>Help</p>
    </div>

    <div class="App_gateway container">
      <h4>Install App</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

You can also try this [Fiddle for Sahil](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/8cjnk9wf/). This version allows the `footer` to stretch full width and divides each column width for equal spacing.